# Type '[Class]?' has no member '[Variable]'

Tags: swift

I am trying to build a movie archive app for iOS. But i am getting this error when i try to use my class which i defined in another controller.

> Type 'Movie?' has no member 'name'

I have 4 Controller files;

- movieListVC
- movieDetailVC
- movieAddVC

and 2 .swift files;

- File
- Movie (this is the file I defined my class)

Movie.swift:

```
class Movie: NSObject {
  var name : String
  var director : String
  var year : String
  var posterURL : String

  override init(){
      self.name = ""
      self.director = ""
      self.year = ""
      self.posterURL = ""
  }
}
```

I can reach my class when I use movieListVC like it should be.

movieListVC:

```
var selectedMovie : Movie?

            .
            .
            .

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  self.selectedMovie = Movie()
  let temp = self.movies[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

  selectedMovie!.name = temp["name"]! as! String
  selectedMovie!.director = temp["director"] as! String
  selectedMovie!.year = temp["year"] as! String
  selectedMovie!.posterURL = temp["posterURL"] as! String

  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: self)

  let movieName = temp["name"] as! String
  print("Name of the selected movie: \(movieName)")
}
```

Xcode doesn't give any error for my movieListVC, but when i use same thing in movieDetailVC, it gives me the error.

movieDetailVC:

```
var movieToShow : Movie?                             // Expected member name or constructor call after type name
            .
            .
            .
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   if (self.movieToShow == nil) {
       return;
   }

   labelMovieName.text = movieToShow!.name           // Type 'Movie?' has no member 'name'
   labelMovieDirector.text = movieToShow!.director   // Type 'Movie?' has no member 'name'
   labelMovieYear.text = movieToShow!.year           // Type 'Movie?' has no member 'name'
   let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: 
             URL(string: movieToShow!.posterURL)))   // Type 'Movie?' has no member 'name'
   imageViewPoster.image = image
}
```

Edit 1: I also use movieToShow in here for information:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: Any!) {
    if segue!.identifier == "detail" {
        let viewController:movieDetailViewController = segue!.destination as! movieDetailViewController

        viewController.movieToShow = self.selectedMovie
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where do you assign a value to `movieToShow`? It looks like a double optional (`??`). By the way your overwritten `init` method is very inefficient. Either declare default values or write a *real* initializer and use `let` constants (preferable).

Comment: @vadian Declaring default values fixed my problem, thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

In the `movieDetailVC`,

```
labelMovieName.text = movieToShow!.name.          // Type 'Movie?' has no member 'name'
```

In the above line, you have used an extra **`.`** after `name`. Remove that.

Comment: Sorry mistyped when spacing. There is no dot in the code.